# How to get the clear 'X' button inside the input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I created a search field where the user can type some text. Next to the search field, is an 'X' button which is there to clear of search inputs. The problem I notice is that, on my phone, the 'X' button is just outside of the input search box: [Here is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2fN8.png). How can I get the 'X' to be inside the search box?

HTML:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search Text...">
<button class="clear">X</button>
```

CSS:

```
#myInput{
    width: 40%;
    height: 33px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-family: 'arial';
    font-size: 19px;
}
.clear {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: -29px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0px none;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: `type="search"` does it in most browsers already

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this is to wrap the input and button in an element with `position: relative` + `width: min-content`. Then you only need to apply `position: absolute` + `right: value` to the button

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: min-content;
}

.clear {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search Text...">
  <button class="clear">X</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="search" />
```

Works in Chromium-based browsers at least. It does have some undocumented side effects though, like <kbd>ESC</kbd> will clear the input.

---

If you're intent on using your own custom clear button, adapt this idea by putting both elements into a shared parent element. Have the `input` take up the entire size of the parent element, and then use `position: absolute;` on the Clear button.